# Free Error / Heap Corruption in Fortran depends on the index that is out of bounds

Tags: fortran, free, gfortran, heap-corruption, intel-fortran

I have a complicated model - to convoluted to post here - and I am trying to debug some strange behavior. I occasionally get free / heap corruption errors at the end of the model run when it is deallocating memory. I can reproduce this behavior in Windows visual fortran and linux gfortran.

I have created a simple test program [hello.f90](https://gist.github.com/dstuebe/7936460) which reproduces some of the really strange behavior that I see in our application.

Any time the bounds of an array are exceeded - shame on me - it is the programmer's fault, but this behavior makes it really hard to figure out! Depending on the index that is exceeded - first or second of a 2D array - the program will raise a heap corruption error on deallocation or proceed without error when compiled with optimization.

Depending on whether line 23/24 is called, the behavior is totally different!

Obviously the thing to do is compile with check all and get a trace back to the line where the error occurs - but this still seems like bad behavior. I am really curious if someone can at least explain what is happening here!

Comment: Posted on intel forum as well: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/496092

Comment: I downvoted, because I don't see the point of the question. Actually, I'm hard pressed to see a question at all; just a call for discussion/guesswork. The problem is known: indexing an array outside its declared bounds. Fix it. It is well documented that it can cause behavior that changes from run to run, depending on many factors.

Comment: With a little distance from the problem, I see that you are right. I did not ask the question clearly (at all?). Lets try this again. I have a realy program with hundreds of arrays that are allocated and indexed based on user input. I am working to add validation code, but in the mean time it would be a great help to have a way to determine which variable caused the problem when deallocation fails. The windows exceptions are generally useless and I am struggling with the minidump. Suggestions? See other comments in the intel forum post too...

Answer (score 4):

If you index an array out of bounds anything can happen. It is an undefined behavior according to the standard. That's why there is the `check` option you mentioned - to specify what happens at least for the particular implementation. But the program runs slower then.

What really happens is that you probably (you didn't show the actual error messages!) rewrite the internal bookkeeping data structures of the memory allocator (malloc) and the error is then raised when the allocator tries to use that damaged information.

Comment: All I get in the error is what is posted in the comments below the test code one for windows/ifort, one for linux/gfortran.
Is there any way to tell in a more complex application what array caused the error - say from a minidump file?

Comment: Your best option is to avoid illegal subscript usage.  Until you are confident that your program has none, it is best to have runtime subscript checking.  My experience is that for most programs the runtime CPU cost is low.  There are exceptions, with substantial runtime increases.  Illegal subscripting can corrupt the internal bookkeeping or overwrite other variables.  The possible consequences are manifold and difficult to trace to the root cause.

Comment: Agreed - I did not create this beast of a program, I am trying to fix issues in an old application written by someone else. Input files are used to allocate and index into arrays. I am working to add validation code, but it would really help if I could figure out which array caused the eventual exception during deallocation, even if I can't get the stack trace to the actual cause without bounds checking. This application can run for over 100 hours when optimized and double that with bounds checking! Have pity on me and stop voting down my question.

Comment: Illegal subscripting is an error that should be fixed even if the program doesn't cause an error during deallocation.  Subscript errors can cause the program to give wrong answers that are hard to notice.

Comment: Totally agree. I can see where you thought I was suggesting that only the ones which caused heap errors should be fixed! 
I am particularly interested when/why an error is caused because I want to find all of them, not just the ones that cause an error. 
Hard to notice is an understatement in a program where variables are indexed by user derived input. As I said above, I am working on adding validation...